# How do I set width of paragraph tab in delphi?

Tags: delphi-2010

What is the meaning of the number assigned to tab[] in the code below. I do not get the actual numbers to set for my tabs. Is the number related to the length of text in each tab? Do I use trial and error until I get columns right?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      red.Paragraph.TabCount := 4;
      red.Paragraph.Tab[0] := 200;
      red.Paragraph.Tab[1] := 100;
      red.Paragraph.Tab[2] := 150;
      red.Paragraph.Tab[3] := 200;

      red.Lines.Add('Test 1 Test 1 ' + #9 + 'Test 2' + #9 + 'Test 3' + #9 +'Test 4' + #9 +'Test 5');
    end;
```

Comment: Try the documentation for the underlying windows rich edit control

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the number  is if you use example

Var
sName,sSurname,sNickname : string;

Begin
 RedOutput.lines.add(sName+ #9 +  sSurname + #9 + sNickname );
End;

In this case the number of columns are counted up from 0 so the [0] is name .....surname , the first #9

The width of the brackets meaning the column is the value you give to it.

The value you are giving is not increasing it can be ...

```
  red.Paragraph.TabCount := 4;
  red.Paragraph.Tab[0] := 100;
  red.Paragraph.Tab[1] := 150;
  red.Paragraph.Tab[2] := 200;
  red.Paragraph.Tab[3] := 250;
```

The numbers 100,150,200,250 is how big the gap between the columns is